# how can I highlight only background of the text on touch on a UILabel

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

In my app, I have modified the UILabel and made it underline the text if the phone number or email appears.

but I want to highlight the text when the phone number or email is touched as shown below (I want something like what has been shown below by the dark gray highlight in background of the text "http://www.foodreporter.net".

I want to do this without use of CoreText as my app targets from iOS 3.1.2 onwards. So I don't want to use the CoreText and Attributed strings.

[image]

I want to subclass the UILabel and do it somehow. How can it be done?

I don't have the option to use OHAttributedLabel and TTTAttributedLabel.

Comment: I don't think you can just "highlight" part of a label's text or even set part of it's background. Either you use a second label/btn which can be formatted or you might overlay with a semi-transparent view/button/etc and create a different background appearance of this part of the text in the label... - or just use a textView with url detection on, then everything is automatic anyway...

Comment: Why don't you have the option of using my `OHAttributedLabel` class? is your project targeted to pre-iOS4 (then pre-CoreText) devices?

Comment: @AliSoftware: Yes my app is targeted for iOS 3.1.2 onwards.. Is there anything else I can try which can help me?

Comment: W/O CoreText I don't see a direct solution, but i've not searched. You will probably use NSString UIKit additions to compute the size of the NSString up to the part being highlighted, compute the size of the text to be highlighted, and compute the CGRects needed to draw the highlight... all of this manually... But it will probably be painful. Maybe there is a better solution, I just don't have it and let others who may know one answer you _(Note: you should mention in your question that you are targetting 3.1.2, it may influence the answers others can propose)_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest for a workaround. What you can do is, use custom UIButton instead of label. Set the default and highlighted image of the button according to your need.(Simple text for default, and highlighted text for highlighted).

Happy Programming

Comment: Are you sure we can't do it by subclassing UILabel?